# how can I remove a faucet nut in a very tight space

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, sink

I need to remove several faucets. The faucet nuts are in a very tight space, in several places recessed into a hole in the basin (see the first two photos). There's no space to get a basin wrench, crescent wrench, or even vice grips in there. The nut does have two notches - is there a tool that can mate with those notches from below? In the third picture, there's a little more space but still not enough to get a basin wrench in there. Is a really deep socket my best bet? Something else?

Thanks for your help!

p.s. There's another post with a similar question, but the suggestion was a basin wrench and that doesn't work here. Also, he really only needed to replace the valve stem, so the conversation quickly diverted.

[image: Nut recessed into hole in basin]

[image: Better view where you can see the notch]

[image: Slightly more space on this one]

Comment: If you are going to replace the faucet, why not just release the water hoists to make room for the tools. If still have trouble, you may need a sucket and T levers. It will be much easier for two persons to work together (one hold the top and one below).

Comment: Thanks r13. I will of course be removing the water supply connections from the faucet body. The problem is the plywood (to the left) and the basin (to the right) create a recessed well that prevent access with a crescent or basin wrench. Sockets or a really big box wrench may indeed be my only option.

Comment: Try to find the cheap socket for the car sparks plug from the car parts store first, make sure you know the size of the nut. I remember one came with two holes at the end and a short lever bar, it might just work. Spread WD40 to lube the nut before unscrew will help. Good luck.

Comment: Another thought - in such a tight space, install the faucet and tighten it will be much more difficult than removing it without the pipes in the way. So, the nut can be just barely fit without much clamping force. After releasing all pipes, spread WD40, and shake the faucet a little (do not force it), then try the needlepoint pliers which might be just you need.

Comment: Thanks, r13, those are good suggestions. The nut is quite a bit bigger than a sparkplug though. It's been there a while so it may have water deposits or corrosion making it hard to break loose. I'll let you know if your suggestions work. Thanks!!!

Comment: Since you are going to junk the faucet, if space permits, why not try a chisel or long screwdriver with a hammer to knock the nut loose. I'll wait to hear the good news, wish you are successful eventually :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the pipework bits, as they need to come off to allow the body to be removed from the worktop anyway.

Deep sockets are a solution - but likely expensive and may not be easy to find.

I made one using some old pipe of a suitable diameter and a file. Did not take long and worked well - those nuts are usually not too tight.

A plan B is to use a drill and split the nut if it is tight then the socket will work or you can split it both sides and it falls off.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike, looks like sockets or something homemade are my options. Or maybe a big box wrench.